# Can you apply XOR to the following expression?

Tags: logic

So I know that

$$\bar{x}y + x\bar{y} = x \oplus y$$

Can this be applied to something like

$$ \bar{a}\bar{b}cd + ab\bar{c}\bar{d} $$

to get 
$$ab \oplus cd$$

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming I'm interpreting your notation correctly: $\overline{x}$ is "not $x$", etc.)

No, because the negation of $ab$ isn't $\overline{a}\overline{b}$, it's $\overline{a}+\overline{b}$. So you could write $$(\overline a+\overline b)cd+ab(\overline c+\overline d)=ab\oplus cd.$$

Comment: Yea you interpreted it correctly, however, I'm slightly confused. You said no, and then said that the expression is equal to ab XOR cd. Did you mean no as in my method to get to that answer is incorrect or that is isn't possible?\

Comment: I meant, no $\bar a\bar bcd+ab\bar c\bar d$ isn't equal to $ab\oplus cd$. You can substitute $x=ab$ and $y=cd$ into the equation $\bar xy+x\bar y=x\oplus y$, but you can't simplify the left-hand side to $\bar a\bar bcd+ab\bar c\bar d$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the first formula,

$$ab\oplus cd=\overline{ab}cd+ab\overline{cd}=(\bar a+\bar b)cd+ab(\bar c+\bar d)=\bar acd+\bar bcd+ab\bar c+ab\bar d.$$